# How to print all filenames in a directory while running line by line on all the files

Tags: perl, filenames

The program I wrote goes through all the files in directory and sub directories line by line and does some commands the include $counter.
I would like to make a .txt file every line will look like this:

```
<file name> <$counter in the beginning of the file>
```

For example if I have three file a.txt , b.txt and c.txt in file a the counter counts 10 in file b it counts 20 and in file c it counts 30 the file would look like this:

```
a.txt 0
b.txt 10
c.txt 20
```

My program looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "C:/New Folder";   
open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');

# fill up our argument list with file names:
find(sub { if (-f && /\.[c]$/) { push @ARGV, $File::Find::name } }, $dir);
$^I = ".bak";   # supply backup string to enable in-place edit  

foreach $argvv(@ARGV)
{
  while (<>) 
  {
     if ($prev_arg ne $argvv)
     {
       print MYFILE  "$argvv $counter\n";
       $prev_arg = $argvv;
     }   

     #some unrelated line by line code here
     close (MYFILE); 
  }
}
```

What I was trying to do is to make the program print the file name and the counter every time it finishes going through a file and starts another one.

The data.txt file i get is the name of the first file and the counter printed for each line of each file in the directory.
Needless to say that I'm a total noob in Perl so I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you pushing the found files onto @ARGV, rather than an array you have declared?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

- You are using `strict` and `warnings` but you have not declared `$prev_arg` and `$argvv`. The warnings have told you about them.
- You never open a file for reading. Instead, you try to use the `-i` command line switch and an argument list to read from `STDIN`. None of that makes sense to me. Instead, you should be using a normal array and open the files one by one.
- You are using old-fashioned bareword filehandles and the two-argument form of `open`. Instead, please use lexical filehandles as they are not global but only exist in their surrounding block. Use the three-argument form of `open` so you don't run into security problems. See [here](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html).

Try this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $dir = 'D:/temp';   

my @files;
find(
  sub {
    if (-f && /\.c.txt$/) {
      push @files, $File::Find::name }
    },
  $dir
);

open my $fh_out, '>>', 'data.txt'   # open the output filehandle
  or die $!; 
foreach my $file (@files) {         # iterate the file list
  open my $fh_in, '<', $file        # open the current file for reading
    or die $!; 
  my $counter = <$fh_in>;           # read the first line
  chomp $counter;                   # remove trailing linebreak
  close $fh_in; 
  print $fh_out "$file $counter\n"; # close the input filehandle (explicit)
}
close $fh_out;                      # close the output filehandle
```